# Why does SQLite not use indexes when you use 'IS' instead of '='?

Tags: sql, sqlite, indexing

This query will not use the index: `SELECT * FROM baz WHERE id IS '123'`

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/7e299/2

This query will use the index: `SELECT * FROM baz WHERE id='123'`

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/7e299/1

Why??

EDIT: I realize there is the stupid answer of expanding the IS to get the correct effect (i.e. making the query `SELECT * FROM baz WHERE id='123' OR '123' IS NULL`, but I am still curious why this is the case.

Comment: `... IS '123'` is invalid SQL. I'm surprised it runs at all.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name its perfectly valid SQLite, however (and quite useful too). The specific use case is when your query is something like `SELECT * FROM foo WHERE bar IS ?` so that you can legitimately pass in `NULL` and have it work.

Comment: I understand that it runs in SQLite - but I'm still surprised.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need to support indexing for such queries.

First, that's just how the [query optimizer works](http://www.sqlite.org/optoverview.html):

```
To be usable by an index a term must be of one of the following forms:

  column = expression
  column > expression
  column >= expression
  column < expression
  column <= expression
  expression = column
  expression > column
  expression >= column
  expression < column
  expression <= column
  column IN (expression-list)
  column IN (subquery)
  column IS NULL
```

For the `IS` operator, [`NULL` values are special](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html):

> The IS and IS NOT operators work like = and != except when one or both of the operands are NULL. In this case, if both operands are NULL, then the IS operator evaluates to 1 (true) and the IS NOT operator evaluates to 0 (false). If one operand is NULL and the other is not, then the IS operator evaluates to 0 (false) and the IS NOT operator is 1 (true).

In your question,

```
SELECT * FROM baz WHERE id IS '123'
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM baz WHERE id='123' OR id IS NULL
```

are not the same thing. (The latter can be satisfied using two index lookups.) It should be something like

```
SELECT * FROM baz WHERE id='123' OR (id IS NULL AND '123' IS NULL)
```

where the parenthesized expression is always false and therefore useless.

So `IS` and `IS NOT` is really only useful when used with `NULL` operand. With regular literal operand it is the same as `=` (or `!=`). And `IS NULL` can be satisfied by an index.

Comment: Yes, you are correct I translated the query incorrectly. However, that being said, the correct transformation can still be used with an index as it simply evaluates to `WHERE id='123'`, right? So, in short, the answer is that SQLite doesnt do it just because it doesnt, not for some actual reason. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes I think so. Choosing to be small and simple instead of catering for all imaginable cases.

Comment: I think that SQLite already does query rewriting and I thought that this was simply syntactic sugar and got rewritten via the translation you gave. If that were the case the optimizations and uses of indicies would have been applied with no additional effort. Since this does not appear to happen, I assume that for some reason this query does not get rewritten.